# Binary equation

Tags: math, binary, equation

I have a task:
`0x430 = ((0x0f0f)^x) << 4) & 0xc35`

which is in decimal:
`1072 = ((3855^x)<<4 & 3125)`

and in binary:
`10000110000 = (111100001111^x)<<4 & 110000110101`

so the first move should be get `110000110101` to the left side. Should I use `or` instead of `and` (&)?

Comment: "I have a task", please elaborate, I only see an equation (and that already assumes it is not an assignment, keep in mind we are programmers here). Please clarify what you mean by `^` we programmers see a XOR there, but you might mean exponentiation.

Comment: @Yunnosch yes, sorry, should clarify. Of course ^ is XOR and & is bitwise AND

Comment: Please explain your task. What are you supposed to do with that eqauation? Determine the only matching x is impossible, so that is not your task. Please explain.

Comment: What are the ranges of the values here? The use `<<` operator frequently but not always assumes a certain fixed width where bits that are shifted "off the left edge" simply disappear and 0 bits enter from the right. So what is that fixed width?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk, yea, you are right, it was supposed to fit into int so max 16 bits. `Determine the only matching x is impossible`, to be honest I can't believe into it - it's just equation, how it can be impossible? Maybe the stupidest solution would be write a program and in loop try all values and compare with result?
The original problem was: `int var = ((0x0F0F ^ x) << 4) & 0xC35` and the question what should be `x` to get `0x430`

Comment: I stand with "impossible". You lose information, so you cannot determine all bits of x. Which in turn means that there are more than one x which do not contradict the equation. Hence there is not only a single x. So it is impossible to determine the "**the only matching x**".

Comment: `Maybe the stupidest solution would be write a program and in loop try all values and compare with result?`. That's what I would do. I don't know if it's stupid but it's easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` operation, assuming you mean bitwise AND, is an operation which loses information. All the information contained in the bits which are "anded" with 0 are lost. It is like mutiplying with 0. There is not equivalent "inverse" operation for multiplication with 0, which, if applied to both sides of the equation remove it on the right and does some change on the left.

I believe hence that your approach of equivalent operations on both sides is not applicable here.

I propose hence, to introduce a different representation for those bits which are lost by being anded with 0. E.g. "#".

That would result in

```
10000110000 = (111100001111^x)<<4 & 110000110101
  =>
1####11#0#0 = (111100001111^x)<<4
```

I.e. you can only determine some of the bits of the unknown "x".

Comment: Agreed, but I think your last line should read `10###11#0#0` instead of `1####11#0#0`.
It may also be worth mentioning that bits are also lost on the `<<` operation if it overflows. So we could have `####0000010###11 = 111100001111^x` or something like that.

Comment: @DillonDavis The part after the `& ` is wider than the part before. You could argue that the result is 01####11#0#0, but I droppen the leading 0. I did not cover the next step, the one to eliminate the `<<`, because OP did not ask about it and because I did not want to discuss the width topic.

Comment: While OP did not request that explicitly, stackoverflow is a knowledge repository, and future readers who stumble upon this question may find such information useful. At least now it is mentioned, even if merely in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

So following not the most clever but working solution:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++){
            if((((3855^i) << 4) & 3125) == 1072){
                System.out.println("Found: " + i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

/*
checking:
left side:
((111100001111 ^ 1000000) << 4) & 110000110101

       111100001111
XOR    000001000000
       111101001111

111101001111 << 4 = 1111010011110000


          1111010011110000
AND       0000110000110101
          0000010000110000


right side: 10000110000

right: 0000010000110000
left:       10000110000
 */
```

as we can see `64` is the first integer bigger than `0` which solves this equation. Of course many more works as well.

Comment: And would you describe this as exactly what @PresidentJamesK.Polk commented some three hours earlier, or would you like to point out a difference?

Comment: yes, I did exactly what we discussed with @PresidentJamesK.Polk. Should I add anything to describe this solution? I think it's clear enough

Comment: Well, two things come to mind. 1: "This is the solution as proposed by ..." 2: "I realised that finding a single solution is impossible, that is why I decided to look for the smallest of many solutions which match the equation." The latter admittedly because I asked twice what you actually want to do with the equation and told you twice that finding a single solution is impossible, with explanation why. Both would be giving credit to the people who contributed the corresponding input. Then don't forget to accept your own answer, since it is obviously the one you find most helpful.

Comment: Please accept my apology. I missed the fact that the grey was a quote and quoting you.

Comment: @Yunnosch, no worries, all good, thank you for help!

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, with an explanation why that makes sense next to your own answer. I calmed down now (see above comment). Please reconsider and freely decide which answer you find most helpful. I really can live with that. I am not making a fuss to get the 15 points. However, if you know the concept of "moving target question", want to avoid that and really appreciate my answer as helpful, then I respect your style and fairness.

Comment: I keep my slightly emotional comment, I stand with my mistakes and it is needed to understand this comment thread. Maybe it gets deleted completely...